# How to integrate Microsoft Graph in an ASP.NET Core Web Api project?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing an SPA using Vue.js and ASP.NET Core. In this SPA I want to show some data from the Azure Active Directory. For this I want to use Microsoft Graph. For this I add in Azure the API permission (application permission) called Directory.Read.All. How can I integrate Microsoft Graph in my ASP.NET Core project? I found no examples. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this what you want?       https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph

Comment: Thanks. I read this article. I am searching for a sample in ASP.NET Core. I do not know what I have to change in the Startup.cs ...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the Following tutorials/samples for more information on how to configure MS Graph with ASP.Net core projects.

[ASP.NET Core MVC apps with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core)

[ASP.NET Core Web API, which calls Microsoft Graph on-behalf of the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/2-web-api-now-calls-microsoft-graph/)